# Pinterest mimic js (jquery) not recalculating unless refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

Im hoping someone will be able to shed some light and help me solve this problem.

Using the following js: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/ we are mimicking the pinterest style of grid layout.

We have this loading on multiple pages and an issue occurs where say im on the homepage and then navigate to a portfolio which has the same effect the grid system is overlapped slightly - as if there is a cache in the calculation somewhere which is causing this, it resolves itself with a refresh of the page but then the homepage is then thrown out and a refresh is needed to sort this out and round and round and round.

I have tried to avoid a cache using several methods (adding a php timestamp variable onto the end of the js file where it is being loaded in. I have tried loading in different files on different pages using modules (we are building on joomla) - `if count module-a show isotope.pkgd.min.1.js else if count module-b show isotope.pkgd.min.2.js` and this still doesnt work.

Any ideas as to why this would be happening and how I can get round this?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** code is too long to post, here is a link to js file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3oghom32961chrl/isotope.pkgd.min.js?dl=0

It is being called in: `<div id="containerNew" class="js-isotope" data-isotope-options='{ "columnWidth": 200, "itemSelector": ".row" }'>`
The itemSelector changes per page.

Any other information required let me know.

**EDIT:** I actually worked this out. The boxes needed a height to be specified if on multiple pages as for the script to recalculate positions.

Comment: And we can answer this with no code provided?

Comment: Added more info, any more required let me know

Comment: can you share the website where you've implemented it & also can the see the issue you're telling about. FYI the code you've attached is the plugin js thats of not much use.

Comment: We don't need the plugin code, we need to see YOUR code! The problem is not in the plugin but how you are using it.